# Longest common substring with constant memory?

Tags: algorithm

Given two strings -- how can you find the longest common substring using only constant memory?

UPDATE: The time constraints are to solve it in O(len1 * len2), like the standard dynamic-programming solution.

Comment: Is this like "given only 14 bytes of memory available, how can you implement a quicksort algorithm", or is there a practical usage of this? At the very least, I'd say that the amount of memory necessary would depend on the length of the strings involved, unless "constant" means "really big ass number that nobody is ever going to need"...

Comment: But the point of homework is not to ask how someone else would do it, it is about figuring it out yourselves, otherwise you're not going to learn why that is a good, or as in this case, a bad solution. A pure brute-force approach, that would surely use constant memory, would suck ass like there's no tomorrow. The point of a homework question is not about getting the answer, it is about understanding what that *is* the answer, and understanding *what the answer is*. In this case, it is *not a good idea*. It's like teaching that an axe is sharp, but not telling you why that might be bad.

Answer (score 3):

Constant memory and *no time constraints*?

Just do a brute force approach: compare all possibilities, keeping just 6 integer indexes in memory: `start` and `end` for both strings, plus 2 for the longest string found yet...